# After running map reduce hdfs going to safe mode in horton works sand box

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hortonworks-data-platform

The Error I got is as follows, is this error occuring because of under or over replication while writing to out put file?

Could not find job application_1417871611451_0016. The job might not be running yet.

> Job job_1417871611451_0016 could not be found:
>   {"RemoteException":{"exception":"NotFoundException","message":"java.lang.Exception:
>   job, job_1417871611451_0016, is not
>   found","javaClassName":"org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.NotFoundException"}}
>   (error 404)

Comment: Did you recently upgraded your hadoop version?

Comment: No, I am working on Horton works sand box 2,1, If I run perticular map reduce this is happening, then if I switch safe mode off using hdfs command then, other jobs are working fine.

Comment: safe mode is not meant to run mapred. You need to come out of safe mode to run map red.

Comment: I am coming out of safe mode, while trying to run again its again going back to safe mode.